# Android Admob banner not viewing only in a certain context

Tags: android, xml, layout, admob

I have an activity that i'm trying to display admob banner in but it would never appear specially in this activity, i have revised the parameter with other activites and xml files and there is nothing different except of coarse in the java code logic behind and the xml designs , anything else related to calling an admob banner is identical .

xml code

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="#CCFF0FF0"
 >
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="myid" />
    <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/AutoCompleteTextView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Search" >

        <requestFocus />
    </AutoCompleteTextView>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:gravity="right" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/a"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:text="a" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/b"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

             android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="b" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/c"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:text="c" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/afragment"
            android:name="Fragments.Afragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

my java code looks exactly like that of the tutorial, i will not post my full since the part requesred

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private InterstitialAd interstitial;
AdView adView;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Get the view from activity_main.xml
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Prepare the Interstitial Ad
    interstitial = new InterstitialAd(MainActivity.this);
    // Insert the Ad Unit ID
    interstitial.setAdUnitId("myid");

    //Locate the Banner Ad in activity_main.xml
     adView = (AdView) this.findViewById(R.id.adView);

    // Request for Ads
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()

    // Add a test device to show Test Ads
     .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
            .build();

    // Load ads into Banner Ads
    adView.loadAd(adRequest);
//      adView.
    // Load ads into Interstitial Ads
    interstitial.loadAd(adRequest);

    // Prepare an Interstitial Ad Listener
    interstitial.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        public void onAdLoaded() {
            // Call displayInterstitial() function
            displayInterstitial();
        }
        @Override
        public void onAdOpened() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onAdOpened();
        }
    });

public void displayInterstitial() {
    // If Ads are loaded, show Interstitial else show nothing.
    if (interstitial.isLoaded()) {
        interstitial.show();
    }
 }
 }
```

The Ad banner place is reserved at run time but with nothing appearing!

Comment: You are using the correct id? `ads:adUnitId="myid"`. What is the logs after the ad is getting requested from your app.

Comment: are you using the same `AdUnitId` for both the banner and interstitial? if so that's the root of your problem

Comment: yes i'm sure of the correct id , and no i'm not using the same AdUnitId for interstitials and banner.

Comment: by the way interstitials appear normally while banner not.

Comment: Post your logcat - it will show what is happening on ad request and response. NB showing your interstitial from `onAdLoaded()` is likely to get your account banned.

Comment: @William i will be posting my logcat soon, however for the banning issue, have you taken a look at the last admob implementation ?
http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/integrating-new-google-admob-banner-interstitial-ads/

Comment: Umm ..  androidbegin is note from the Android or Admob team. And their example is giving you exactly the **wrong** information. This is what you want https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/android/quick-start

Comment: i have tracked your comments to the publisher in the website i posted and  figured out that that you are a Google Developer Expert for Admob, thank you for your note
Again,  i will be posting my logcat soon.

Comment: ok ,  the logcat says that the ad does not have enough space to display, this is because my activity is of type dialog , i have tried to change the adsize to smartbanner from the xml file but i still get the same message, does this mean i can't use a banner with a dialog activity ? 
@William